# Determine if the function $B:\mathbb{R}^3\times\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ defines an inner product.

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

> I have to determine that this function:
>
> $$
> \text{B(x,y)} = \begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2&x_3\end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix}1&1&1\\1&3&1\\1&1&5\end{bmatrix}
> \begin{bmatrix}y_1\\y_2\\y_3\end{bmatrix}
> $$
>   defines an inner product.

So I'm pretty sure i have to show that this function satisfies bilinearity, symmetry and positive definite. I'm watching a solution to this on online lectures, but I could not follow the lecturer on the bilinearity  part.
He used the fact that the function $B=x^TBy$ because of the distributivity law of matrix multiplication.

Can anyone expand on showing that this function is bilinear?

Comment: $(x,y) \mapsto B(x,y)$ is an inner product on $\mathbb{R}^3$ if and only if the matrix 

$$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 3 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 & 5 \end{bmatrix} $$

is symmetric positive definite.

Comment: @jibounet Thats not what OP is asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bilinearity part:

1. $B(x_1+x_2,y)=(x_1+x_2)^TBy=(x_1^T+x_2^T)By=x_1^tBy+x_2^TBy)=B(x_1,y)+B(x_2,y)$

and for $t \in \mathbb R$ we have

$B(tx,y)=(tx)^TBy=tx^TBy=tB(x,y)$.

2. It is now your turn to show that $B$ is linear in the second argument $y$.

Comment: that was awesome. Thankyou.

Comment: $B(x,y_1+y_2)=x^TB(y_1+y_2)=x^TBy_1+x^TBy_2=B(x,y_1)+B(x,y_2)$

Answer (score 1):

$$B(x, y+y') = x^TB(y+y') = x^T(B(y+y')) = x^T(By+By') = x^T(By) + x^TBy'$$

if any one of the steps above is unclear, please ask.

You can prove the other bilinearity properties in a similar way. Just remember that $(x^T B)y=x^T(By)$.

Comment: thanks for your help also.